# Parse Error using vision.VideoPlayer

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, parse-error, matlab-cvst

While trying to use `vision.VideoPlayer` I get the following error:

> Error using vision.VideoPlayer The specified superclass
>   copeextensions.AbstractSystemObjectScope' contains a parse error or
>   cannot be found on Matlab's search path, possibly shadowed by another
>   file with the same name.
>
> Error in virtualtrycolorm 19
>
> Matlab:class:InvalidSuperClass

Actually I have created a exe file from MATLAB using `deploytool`. While trying to execute the exe file I'm getting the error. Here is the code which causes it:

```
function virtualtrycolorm(~,~,~)     
redthresh = 0.25;     
greenthresh = 0.06;    
bluethresh = 0.15;    
import java.awt.Robot;     
import java.awt.event.*;   
varimouse = Robot;    
camera1=imaqhwinfo;    
cameraname=char(camera1.InstalledAdaptors(end));    
camerainfo=imaqhwinfo(cameraname);    
cameraid=camerainfo.DeviceInfo.DeviceID;     
cameraformat=char(camerainfo.DeviceInfo.SupportedFormats(end));
vid  = imaq.VideoDevice(cameraname, cameraid, cameraformat, 'ReturnedColorSpace', 'RGB');
vidinfo = imaqhwinfo(vid); 
screenSize = get(0,'ScreenSize');
blob = vision.BlobAnalysis('AreaOutputPort', false, 'CentroidOutputPort', true, 'BoundingBoxOutputPort', true','MaximumBlobArea', 4500, 'MinimumBlobArea', 100, 'MaximumCount', 3);
shapeins = vision.ShapeInserter('BorderColorSource', 'Input port', 'Fill', true,'FillColorSource', 'Input port', 'Opacity', 0.4);
%% here is the error:
videoPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer('Name', 'Final Video', 'Position', [100 100 800 500]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use `vision.VideoPlayer` with deploytool.  If you are on Windows, use `vision.DeployableVideoPlayer` instead.